# losing session data in asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session

My IIS session occasionally loses all data stored in it, it usually takes about 3-5 minutes, but definately less then the session timeout set in the web.config. The problem is not reproducible reliably, when it happens, accoring to the logs the AppPool is not recycled and the Session ID remains the same, it just loses all data. Any suggestions on how to debug this?

So far I tried to overwrite the session provider and stored the session data into a static variable, we checked all relevant timeouts and we stored a dummy value in the session, that is lost as well

Answer (score 0):

A number of things can cause session state to mysteriously disappear.

1. Your sessionState timeout has expired
2. You update your web.config or other file type that causes your AppDomain to recycle
3. Your AppPool in IIS recycles
4. You update your site with a lot of files, and ASP.NET proactively destroys your AppDomain to recompile and preserve memory.

If you are using IIS 7 or 7.5, here are a few things to look for:

1. By default, IIS sets AppPools to turn themselves off after a period of inactivity.
2. By default, IIS sets AppPools to recycle every 1740 minutes (obviously depending on your root configuration, but that's the default)
3. In IIS, check out the "Advanced Settings" of your AppPool. In there is a property called "Idle Time-out". Set that to zero or to a higher number than the default (20).
4. In IIS, check the "Recycling" settings of your AppPool. Here you can enable or disable your AppPool from recycling. The 2nd page of the wizard is a way to log to the Event Log each type of AppPool shut down.

If you are using IIS 6, the same settings apply (for the most part but with different ways of getting to them), however getting them to log the recycles is more of a pain. Here is a link to a way to get IIS 6 to log AppPool recycle events:

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I can rule out updates to the web.config and the various timeouts for sure, I will configure IIS to log AppPool events to the Event Log now, thanks for that tip

Comment: @larkre If this answer is helpful for this question then vote up and accept the answer, Other people those who are finding info related to this question they will get the answer here.